# filter all columns to exclude "-" in rows

Tags: microsoft-excel

for example, I have a data set like so:

[image]

If i filter col 2 to exclude `-`  , i will miss values in other columns and vice versa.

Does anyone know a way where I can include all values while filtering out rows that all have `-` ?

I need all Col 1 values that correspond to Col 2,3,4 that are having `-` , to be excluded. For example I would only exclude row 6.

Comment: Add a helper column with the following formula: `=SUM(B2:D2)` Then filter out the ones that are `0` in that helper column.

Comment: Thanks Scotty 2 Hotty!

Comment: Please mark as answered.